# How to use rxjs operators inside a TypeScript app

Tags: typescript, webpack, rxjs

I have a very Typescript app and I want to use rxjs.

I did:

```
npm install --save-dev rxjs
```

then in the file main.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

function test() {
    Observable.from([0,1,2,3,4])
    .filter((x) => x >= 2)
    .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'rxjs/add/observable/from'
```

In case you need: [here is my gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/VivienAdnot/b67c72dcf36811aac99707197478868a), using Webpack

Do you know what I'm missing ?
Thank you guys

Comment: Can you check your `typescript` and `rxjs` versions? This should work fine...

Comment: typescript: 2.0.9, rxjs: 5.0.1

Comment: This works without webpack so have a look at webpack configuration because this this is typescript unrelated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was checking your `webpack.config.js`, where you missed to add the resolvable extensions.

The webpack says,

> An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules. For
>   example, in order to discover CoffeeScript files, your array should
>   contain the string ".coffee".
>
> Default: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]
>
> IMPORTANT: Setting this option will override the default, meaning that
>   webpack will no longer try to resolve modules using the default
>   extensions. If you want modules that were required with their
>   extension (e.g. require('./somefile.ext')) to be properly resolved,
>   you must include an empty string in your array. Similarly, if you want
>   modules that were required without extensions (e.g.
>   require('underscore')) to be resolved to files with “.js” extensions,
>   you must include ".js" in your array.

Since you are overriding the webpack's default resolve extension options, you have to tell the webpack that, please resolve the modules which has `['.js', '.ts', '']` extensions.