# Should I use both `import 'rxjs/Rx'` and `import { Observable } from '@rxjs/Observable'`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from '@rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
@Component({});
export shellModule{}
```

This is a piece of code form my Angular app that I copied from somewhere (I have removed the definitions in the exported module. I am using it to make a service to call APIs.

In the imports in this particular file, why is it that Observable is imported separately even though the entire **rxjs**has been imported. If a particular module is being imported in its entirety, why is a particular object from it imported separately? I tried asking this question at the forum from where I took it, but there was no answer. I want to understand if this somehow helps with optimization of code.

Comment: Not even sure that line works at all, the package name is rxjs, so it should not find something like @rxjs. You should only import the types like Observable, Subject, etc. separately and import individual operators as needed.

Comment: Additionally a good practice would be to organise all the operator imports into one file like rxjs.imports.ts and have them only there. You only need to import them once to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*In general*:

In Typescript, the way [modules are handled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) would require you to either load in the entire library with the `import * as rx from 'rxjs/Rx'`, or a specific exported module within the library to use it, so the the compiler loads in the types.

Reducing your imports to only the specific modules you need sets up your app to use tree shaking from [Angular's AOT compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler). This is not done by the typescript compiler, but by a [tool called rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup). So, it *can* help with optimizing code later, but it doesn't automatically do so.

As far as compilation overhead, bringing in the whole library might slow down the compiler a bit... but this isn't a very strong point except for massively complex libraries.

I, personally, prefer importing in specific modules because it makes the calling code a little cleaner since I don't need to use that global name to get to the specific name. `rx.Observable` vs `Observable`. A good example of this is the lodash library (rxjs is a bit more complex...)

Honestly, importing entire libraries like the line you have there: `import 'rxjs/Rx'` doesn't make sense to me. You should only import specific exported modules. Try removing it, seeing what errors you get, and then using the `* as rx` syntax instead.

As far as rxjs goes - it is a little wonky when you want to **import specific operators** like [this question does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221149/how-to-use-rxjs-operators-inside-a-typescript-app) - so the way to get specific operators is with: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/from'` - but that also requires a tinkering with your *webpack* set up as outlined in [the referenced question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221149/how-to-use-rxjs-operators-inside-a-typescript-app).

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what the `rxjs/Rx` module exports:

```
export { Subject, AnonymousSubject } from './Subject';
export { Observable } from './Observable';
export { Operator } from './Operator';
export { Observer } from './Observer';
export { Subscription } from './Subscription';
export { Subscriber } from './Subscriber';
export { AsyncSubject } from './AsyncSubject';
export { ReplaySubject } from './ReplaySubject';
export { BehaviorSubject } from './BehaviorSubject';
...

import './add/observable/bindCallback';
import './add/observable/bindNodeCallback';
import './add/observable/combineLatest';
...
```

So it exports `RxJs` classes and also imports operators from the `add` folder. So as you can see it loads everything in the library. It doesn't export any global object though. So you need to use named export like this:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

to be able to use an exported class:

```
Rx.Observable.of(12, 3);
```

This emulates what you would have if you loaded the library using the bundle - a global `Rx` object:

```
<script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js">
```

If you want to use `Observable` without `Rx` global object, you need to import it separately:

```
import { Observable } from '@rxjs/Observable';
Observable.of(1);
```

Importing both

```
import { Observable } from '@rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

is not a good practice, but may be used if you don't want to import every operator separately.

Also see [How to correctly import operators from the `rxjs` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484025/2545680).