# error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'?

Tags: angular2-services

I have a simple angular2 serive below and while running I m getting the error "error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'". I have imported all the operators but still its not working. any idea on this?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Currency } from './currency';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

private baseUrl: any = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=';

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getCurrencyRates(base: string): Observable<Currency[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + base)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch(err => err)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question: [Should I use both `import 'rxjs/Rx'` and `import { Observable } from '@rxjs/Observable'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553341/should-i-use-both-import-rxjs-rx-and-import-observable-from-rxjs-obse)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add "import { Observable } from 'rxjs';" and then Try out "import { map } from 'rxjs/operator';" or "import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';" ... instead of "import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';" .I know this has to be added for the Angular 5 but this might run in angular 2 too.

Answer (score 0):

i got this same error,but i did this npm installation,

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

and imported to service file this,

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

it worked...