# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type. even returning Observable<any>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm receiving a compilation error when I try to subscribe to a method in a service, yes I am returning an Observable.

The related versions are from default .net core angular template.

- Angular => 4.4.4
- rxjs => 5.4.2

**VS Code error**

[image: VS Code error.]
Below, the login.component.ts with references.

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { LoginViewModel } from "../models/ApplicationUserViewModel";

import { LoginService } from "../services/Login.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginViewModel: LoginViewModel;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  login(): any {
    this.loginService.login(this.loginViewModel).subscribe(
      result => {
        alert("success");
      },
      error => {
        alert("error");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Below, the login.service.ts with references.

**login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from "rxjs/operator/map";

import { LoginViewModel } from "../models/ApplicationUserViewModel";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
};

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<LoginViewModel>(
      'account/login',
      loginViewModel,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the `imports` section of the class.

Comment: Please add the versions of rxjs/angular that you are using and the import sections in the LoginService

Comment: I updated the Question with angular and rxjs information. thanks.

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553341/should-i-use-both-import-rxjs-rx-and-import-observable-from-rxjs-obse ... The import should be import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: I tried to import Observable from 'rxjs/Observable' but i receive the error 'rxjs/Observable' has no exported member 'Observable'. I believe that it happen due the rxjs version.